# How to display multi-select list from List<MyObject>

Tags: c#, .net, razor, asp.net-mvc-4

```
class User() {
   public List<Customer> Customers;
}

class Customer() {
   public long Id;
   public string Name;
}
```

I populate the selected items

```
User MyUser = new User(); 
MyUser.Customers = db.Customers.Where(...).ToList();
```

I pass the list of all items in this way

```
ViewBag.Customers = db.Customers.OrderBy(c => c.Name).ToList();
```

In my View i want to display it like a multi-select HTML element with all (ViewBag.Customers) elements and (MyUser.Customers) as selected.
I tried with

```
@model MySCL.Models.User

@Html.ListBoxFor(m => m.Customers, new MultiSelectList(ViewBag.Customers, "Id", "Name"), new {Multiple = "multiple", size = "5" })
```

but it display only the complete list without select any items.
Is this the best practice to do it?
Is there another better way?
Instead of a List of Customer if I had a List of string how can I do it?

Comment: Rick Anderson's know the trick http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/javascript/working-with-the-dropdownlist-box-and-jquery/using-the-dropdownlist-helper-with-aspnet-mvc

Answer (score 1):

The [MultiSelectList constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd470158%28v=vs.108%29.aspx) also takes an IEnumerable list of items to be selected, so if you change your code to:

```
new MultiSelectList(ViewBag.Customers, "Id", "Name", Model.Customers)
```

The list should then start with all the customer's items selected.

Comment: I want to start with all items (ViewBag.Customers that contains all Customers) in my list and (MyUser.Customers that is a subset of ViewBag.Customers) as selected.

Comment: Then the fourth parameter becomes Model.Customers.

Answer (score 1):

I resolved by passing the 4th parameter as a list of int or string with the only key of the objects and not a list of objects.

```
new MultiSelectList(ViewBag.Customers, "Id", "Name", Model.Customers.Select(c => c.Id))
```